# How to add images instead of dots in a plotly scatter plot (python)

Tags: python, image, plotly, addition

Lets say I have this scatter plot in plotly:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
fig.show()
```

[image]

But instead of the dots I want to add different Images on those particular positions. Something like this:

[image]

Is that possible with plotly? I know that you can [add Images](https://plotly.com/python/images/) but I dont know how to pass the exact coordinates of position where the images should be shown.

I apprecaite your time! Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- a few points on answer

  - no reference was provided to images to use, so downloaded some from kaggle.  Couldn't find emojis.  This bulks up code to do this...
  - **Plotly Express** is used without a data frame in question.  So have kept to this.  This then means loop through x&y values in trace to get position of images
  - effectively image used is random,  could be selected based on features of data

[image]

```
import plotly.express as px
import kaggle.cli
import sys, requests
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import urllib
from PIL import Image

# fmt: off
# download some images to demonstrate
url = "https://www.kaggle.com/anzhemeng/nfl-team-logos"
sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]] + f"datasets download {urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path[1:]}".split(" ")
kaggle.cli.main()
zfile = ZipFile(f'{urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1]}.zip')
# fmt: on
zfile.extractall("nfl-logos")

fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])

# question did not use a dataframe,  so will use x & y from the figure trace
# just a selection of images, used NFL images given don't have emojis
for x,y, png in zip(fig.data[0].x, fig.data[0].y, Path.cwd().joinpath("nfl-logos").glob("*.png")):
    fig.add_layout_image(
        x=x,
        y=y,
        source=Image.open(png),
        xref="x",
        yref="y",
        sizex=2,
        sizey=2,
        xanchor="center",
        yanchor="middle",
    )
    
fig
```

Comment: Hey! What if I want to add the value of y coordinate as the title on each of these images? And is there a way not to overlap the images if the points are plotting near each other?

Comment: @Mr.J `fig.add_annotation(x=x, y=y, text=png.stem)` will label each image.  Overlapping it's down to adding them in order you want them so most important images are at front and less important ones at back